# Returning a next function to call in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Trying to explain solution to a problem i'm trying to solve. Using vue.js or actually it doesn't really matter which framework, it's more of a javascript question. I wrote a module that integrates soundcloud api. The trackBySearchTerm function makes an http request to search for songs with a given term but specifying 5 results per page. Now to get the next page, the response returned by the api contains a property next_href. The next_href is a url used to make the next api call. So I find that my implementation kind of really sucks. This is the module I wrote:

```
import http from 'axios'

const clientId = '1234'
const scApiBaseUrl = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/'
const scBaseUrl = 'http://soundcloud.com/'
const pageSize = 6

export default { 
    tracksBySearchTerm (p, cb) {
        let initialUrl = scApiBaseUrl + 'tracks/' + '?client_id=' + clientId + '&limit=' + pageSize + 
        '&linked_partitioning=1'

        if (p.searchTerm) {
            initialUrl += '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(p.searchTerm)
        }

        let url = p.nextHref || initialUrl

        http.get(url, { withCredentials: false })
            .then((result) => { cb( result.data )  } ) 
    }
}
```

So now the then part of the promise calls the callback with the response from soundclouds api. The part that really sucks is that the next_href is in the response but is provided to the callback function. The tracksBySearchTerm p parameter can contain a nextHref property and if it exists then use that url for the http request. I don't really like this because that means anyone that uses this module can just pass any random url.

So I guess the solution i'm looking for is how can I for instance have tracksBySearchTerm pass a getNextResults function as a parameter to the callback function (obviously with the paged search results), which when called will use the next_href from the previous request to make the api request, also for the next set of pages. This means there could be 10 pages of results. I am also trying to avoid a global next_href variable because the module should just return the next set of results.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on there. But callbacks smell bad. If you're looking for the way to do API requests to different pages in continuous manner, you should probably try RxJS or generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Don't default-export objects with static methods, and don't use callbacks but return promises.

Yes, you can easily construct a new object to return to your caller that has a method that gets the next result. You just use a basic closure:

```
import http from 'axios'

const clientId = '1234'
const scApiBaseUrl = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/'
const scBaseUrl = 'http://soundcloud.com/'
const pageSize = 6

function tracksByUrl(url) {
    return http.get(url, { withCredentials: false }).then(response => {
        return {
            result: response.data,
            next() {
                return tracksByUrl(response.nextHref);
            }
        };
    });
}

export function tracksBySearchTerm (searchTerm) {
    let initialUrl = `${scApiBaseUrl}tracks/?client_id=${clientId}&limit=${pageSize}&linked_partitioning=1`;
    if (searchTerm) {
        initialUrl += '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)
    }
    return tracksByUrl(initialUrl);
}
```